# Calculating time difference in hours

Tags: java

I am a newbie in java. I have written this function to find the time difference in hours from the current time to the time in function parameters. The results are kind of mixed, how I can I improve it? Thanks.

```
private int getTimeDiffFromCurrent(String date, String time)
    {
        String str_date_time = date + " " + time;
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());

        try {
            Date date_time = (Date) formatter.parse(str_date_time); 
            int hr = (int)((System.currentTimeMillis() - date_time.getTime())/(1000 * 60 * 60));
            return hr>=0? hr : 1000;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString() + ", " + str_date_time);
        }    
        return 1000;
    }
```

Example of used case:

`getTimeDiffFromCurrent("19/07/2020", "07:19:00");`

Comment: You should not use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`, as they are obsolete. And they provide problems. Use classes from the `java.time` package instead (API level 26 required). If you target API levels lower than 26, you should use ThreeTen Android Backport, to get a decent date and time API.

Comment: Your string input is incomplete, having only a date and time-of-day. Without the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC, we cannot determine a moment, a specific point on the timeline. So we cannot calculate elapsed time.

Comment: Unfortunately there are still tutorial pages and other material showing newcomers like you how to use `DateFormat`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` — poorly designed and outdated classes that the seasoned ones of us stopped using half a decade ago. You should stop too, immediately. Use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the Java Date and Time API available in the `java.time` package, then it'll becomes much simpler.

```
static long getDifferenceInHours(ZonedDateTime dateTime) {
    ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();
    return Duration
        .between(dateTime, now)
        .toHours();
}
```

You can then call it like this:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(2020, 7, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.systemDefault());
long difference = getDifferenceInHours(zdt);
System.out.println(difference);
```

You shouldn't apply math to calculate date and time differences; there are many APIs out there doing the job pretty well.

I used `ZonedDateTime` in the abovementioned code, because this takes possible DST changes into consideration. For example, in the Europe/Amsterdam timezone, between 29th March 2020, 00:00 and 05:00 are just 4 hours (instead of 5) due to the wall clock skipping an hour at two.